# If property exists, push it to an array

Tags: angularjs, iteration

This technically works, but it feels clunky. Is there a more efficient way to check if a specific property return true, and if it does, push it to an array, and then check for the next desired property, and so on?

For example:

```
    let createHero = {
        name: "OJ",
        trauma1: "abc",
        trauma2: "def",
        nickname: "spool"
    }

    let trauma = [];

      if ( createHero.trauma1 ){
        trauma.push( createHero.trauma1 )
      }
      if ( createHero.trauma2 ){
        trauma.push( createHero.trauma2 )
      }
      if ( createHero.trauma3 ){
        trauma.push( createHero.trauma3 )
      }
      if ( createHero.birthDate ){
        trauma.push( createHero.birthDate )
      }
      if ( createHero.name ){
        trauma.push( createHero.name )
      }

    console.log(trauma) //[ "abc" , "def", "OJ" ]
```

I'm building this inside of an AngularJs-Express application, so I do not want to use Jquery.

What am I missing? Maybe regular expressions can help out?

**UPDATE**

I went with this function largely provided by @andersVestergaard. It allows me to feed it an object and pattern, returning the values of matching properties in an array.

```
      //filter is a regex pattern
     let filterForValues = function(object, filter) { 
        let key, keys = []; 
           for (key in object) { 
              if (object.hasOwnProperty(key) && filter.test(key)) { 
                keys.push(object[key]); 
             } 
          } 
             return keys; 
        } 

        let traumaArray = filterForValues(createHero, /trauma/i);

        console.log(traumaArray); //[ "abc" , "def"]
```

Comment: have you tried with angular.forEach()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand correctly you can loop through the object with for..in like this:

```
 for (var key in createHero ) {
      if (createHero.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        trauma.push(createHero[key]);
      }
 }
```

Comment: Ahhh, this is what I was after. Now, I'm going to add to this so that I can search for several different keys. Thanks!